# Translating a theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am tryign to make my theme translatable so I am using the following command to output text. But its not outputting a default value i thought the __ did that automartically.

```
<?php __('PLAYER POINTS AT A GLANCE.','gogreensoccer');?>
```

I am using the above to display a translatable string to wordpress buts its empty.

```
<div class="skill-title">
            <h3><?php __('PLAYER POINTS AT A GLANCE.','gogreensoccer');?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
            <div class="kids-dashboard-skill">
                <div class="skill-show">
                    <div class="points"><h3><span><?php  echo $player->display( 'points' ); ?></span>POINTS</h3></div>
                    <div class="circle-skill"><div id="circle" data-size="<?php  echo $player->display( 'points' ); ?>" data-thickness="35"></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="skill-button">
                    <center>
                        <button><?php __('VIEW MY TEAM MATES.','gogreensoccer');?></button>
                        <button><?php __('Player ID','gogreensoccer');?><?php echo $playerId;?></button>
                    </center>
                </div>
</div>
```

But im not getting any text outputed obv I want a default value here if no translation exists i though __(string,themename) would achieve this.

Comment: Use `esc_html_e('PLAYER POINTS AT A GLANCE.','gogreensoccer')`. This will echo it and make it translatable, and escape it at the same time :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the right function: `__()` returns the text or the translation if it exists. If you want to display it, you must use `echo` like this: `echo __('some text', 'textdomain')`.

As an alternative, if you just want to print the text, you can use the `_e()` function which will echo the text (the one in parentheses or the translation if it exists). You can use it like this for example: `_('some text', 'textdomain')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [esc_html_e()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_e) function to escape your translatable text and output it.

`_e()` is a shorthand notation for `echo __()`, while `__()` just returns the translated string (not echoing it out).

Anyways, the best practice is to [escape all things](https://vip.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/the-importance-of-escaping-all-the-things/).